# The array A(10) is given. Replace all the elements standing between the largest and the smallest with the number 100

Tags: python

I have a problem with python task
for example:
array [1, 5, 2, 3, -1, 3]
new_array [1, 5, 100, 100, -1, 3]

i dont know how do this cuz i new in python

Comment: What if the input is [3,2,1,2,3]?

Comment: if input [3,2,1,2,3] need output [3,100,2,1,2,3]

Comment: Why not [3,2,1,100,3]?

Comment: @pogmee also there are 6 elements `[3,100,2,1,2,3]` in your expected output

Comment: @KellyBundy i need just easy array for example [1, 5, 2, 3, -1, 3]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my solution works only for this case when maximal value before minimal but you could easily update this solution.

```
array = [1, 5, 2, 3, -1, 3] 
c = []
for i,j in enumerate(array):
if i<=(array.index(max(array))) or i>=array.index(min(array)):
    c.append(j)
else:
    c.append(100)
```

print(c)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the indexes of the minimum and maximum values and then assign a corresponding list of 100s to the subscript:

```
A = [1, 5, 2, 3, -1, 3]

start,end = sorted(map(A.index,(min(A),max(A))))
A[start+1:end] = [100]*len(A[start+1:end])

print(A) # [1, 5, 100, 100, -1, 3]
```

*If you need it to be in a separate variable you can make  copy beforehand (ex: `new_array = array.copy()`) and work on the copy*